# How to disable functionality of <a href>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to disable this:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" onclick="edit_user('<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
```

when user_id = 1. Can someone help me?

Comment: why not just edit `edit_user` `if user_id==1; return`

Comment: It's probably better to not show the link than to try and break it once you've rendered it.

Comment: @tadman agreed, did not think that one through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check in php for $user_id ==1  and echo the code you need

```
<a <?php echo ( $user_id ==1 ) ? '' : 'href="javascript:void(0);"' ?> 
      role="button" onclick="edit_user('<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>')">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="edit_user('<?php echo $data['user_id']; ?>')" <?php echo $data['user_id']==1 ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: its always helpful to explain the code, not just dump it as an answer